# Get messages between friends in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have made a database structure where users can make "friend connection" between them like on facebook. 
Every user can save text to `tbl_Statuses` table and only their friends can see this messages.
But I have trouble with SQL :(

```
tbl_Friends{UserId, FriendId, Accepted}
tbl_Statuses{StatusId, Text, UserId}
```

I'am trying to get statuses:
**- That I write**
**- That my friends write**

I have tried something but I can't figure :(

```
select s.* 
from tbl_Statuses s left join tbl_Friends f on s.userId = f.UserId
where s.userId = f.UserId
```

Comment: what do you have that is strange?  what are you expecting to see and what do you see? you could try adding f.* to your select criteria that might fix your problem if the problem is your not seeing data.

Comment: What is your expected result?. Do you want a list of friends that can see a status?

Comment: I updated question. Basically I need to get everything from tbl_Statuses that me and all my friends write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Statuses
WHERE UserId = @MyUserId 
OR UserId IN (SELECT FriendId FROM tbl_Friends WHERE UserId = @MyUserId AND Accepted = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just need to add if someone build similar thing. Depend on who send request for friendship userId can sometimes be in UserID column and sometimes in FriendID column so to this query I also add: ...OR UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM tbl_Friends WHERE FriendId = 1...)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- What you say
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_StatuseS
 WHERE UserId = @userId
union
-- What your friends say
SELECT s.*
  FROM tbl_Friends f
  join tbl_Statuses s on s.userId = f.FriendId
 WHERE f.UserId = @userId
   and f.Accepted = 1
```